# Rolling up Multiple Rows into a Single Row

Tags: linux, csv-simple

How can I rollup multiple rows from a csv file into 1 row ? I have tried working out the query in SQL and it works but I am not sure how can I achieve the same in Linux.

This is how my current file looks :

```
swainb02,Ben Swain,1015
swainb02,Ben Swain,1016
swainb02,Ben Swain,1018
swainb02,Ben Swain,1020
shaiks21,Sarah Shaikh,0073
shaiks21,Sarah Shaikh,0080
shaiks21,Sarah Shaikh,0082
```

There are multiple users with access to multiple area codes. What I am looking for is a simpler version of this file for better readability.

Desired Output :

```
swainb02,Ben Swain,1015,1016,1018,1020
shaiks21,Sarah Shaikh,0073,0080,0082
```

Any idea how can this be worked out  ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input is grouped by the key values as shown in your question (if not just sort the input first) then using any awk in any shell on every Unix box and using almost no memory no matter how large your input file is:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{ curr = $1 OFS $2 }
curr != prev {
    printf "%s%s", ors, curr
    prev = curr
    ors = ORS
}
{ printf "%s%s", OFS, $3 }
END { printf ors }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
swainb02,Ben Swain,1015,1016,1018,1020
shaiks21,Sarah Shaikh,0073,0080,0082
```

Answer (score 1):

Run a little `awk` script on your results:

```
awk -F, '
$1$2 != Last    {printf DL "%s", $0
                 Last=$1$2
                 DL=ORS
                 next
                }
                {printf ",%s", $3
                }
END             {print ""
                }
' file
swainb02,Ben Swain,1015,1016,1018,1020
shaiks21,Sarah Shaikh,0073,0080,0082
```

It prints new users' data once, and then appends area codes until next user is encountered.

Comment: Note that this would treat records with fields that are identical apart from the placing of the comma as the same (e.g., `aa,bbcc`, `aab,bcc`, and `aabb,cc`). It's unlikely to be an issue with the type of data in the question, but still.

Comment: This also assumes the data is already sorted in the first and second fields.

Comment: In general you can't concatenate 2 strings to get a unique string since `a bc` and `ab c` both concatenate to `abc` so instead of using `$1$2`, use `$1 FS $2` or similar to ensure you get a unique result without having to be concerned about what values the input might contain.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input is simple CSV without embedded commas, newlines or quotes, we may use GNU `datamash` to group by the first two comma-delimited fields and collapse the third field:

```bash
$ datamash -t, groupby 1,2 collapse 3 <file
swainb02,Ben Swain,1015,1016,1018,1020
shaiks21,Sarah Shaikh,0073,0080,0082
```

This assumes that the data is sorted on the first two fields (or that the records that would sort together are adjacent to each other in the file, as in the example data).  If it is not, then pass the data through `sort -t, -k 1,2` first, or use `datamash` with its `-s` (or `--sort`) option.

---

For generic CSV input, use a CSV-aware tool like Miller (`mlr`).  The following does the same operation as above:

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N nest --ivar comma -f 3 file
swainb02,Ben Swain,"1015,1016,1018,1020"
shaiks21,Sarah Shaikh,"0073,0080,0082"
```

Note that since `mlr` is CSV-aware, it properly quotes the combined 3rd field and its embedded commas.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried working out the query in SQL and it works

Great. Then just run `sqlite :memory:` to work without a file backing your database (assuming there's not billions of rows, this should be fine). In there, run (or just pipe this program into the interpreter)

```
.mode csv
.import yourfile.csv users
SELECT … FROM users …; # this is the SQL query that already works!
```

Done. The `sqlite3` client is available practically everywhere and I'd call it the most UNIX-alike method to use a structured query language interpreter to perform a structured query like that. All in all, you could type this into your shell (bash/dash/zsh and similar):

```bash
function runmyquery() {
sql="
.mode csv
.import $1 users
SELECT … FROM users …; # replace with your query!
"
echo "${sql}" | sqlite3 :memory: 
}
```

Afterwards you can just run `runmyquery myfile.csv` and get the result. `sqlite3` can also be used interactively.

Answer (score 0):

This awk version works regardless of the order of the rows:

```
{
  if ($1 "," $2 in a) {
    a[$1 "," $2] = a[$1 "," $2] "," $3
  } else {
    a[$1 "," $2] = $3
  }
}

END {
  for (i in a) {
    print i, a[i]
  }
}
```

On the other hand, csvkit outputs a more correct result:

```
csvsql -H -d ',' --query 'SELECT a,b, GROUP_CONCAT(c) as c FROM data GROUP BY a, b' data.txt
a,b,c
shaiks21,Sarah Shaikh,"73.0,80.0,82.0"
swainb02,Ben Swain,"1015.0,1016.0,1018.0,1020.0"
```

Even though this looks better without quotation marks, another example could easily result in a varying number of fields for each row. For further processing, an output with a delimited third field is highly desirable.